# PyOpenCL - not seeing expected speedup

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

In experimenting with PyOpenCL, I noticed my code was running slower than expected. It turned out that it ran faster on CPU than on GPU (running on PyOpenCL in both cases, achieving just 1 GFLOP).

To debug this, I then tried naive matrix multiplication as a comparison, and only see a 2x speedup on GPU vs CPU (~20 GFLOPs vs ~10 GFLOPs). My system is i7 8750H + GTX 1070 Max-Q.

Does anyone have any thoughts they could share about what I might be doing wrong? I know that the code below is not optimal, but I would have expected that with the much increased floating point capability and memory bandwidth of my GPU there would be a bigger difference.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as pycl_array
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import time

size = 4000

m1 = np.random.normal(size = [size,size]).astype(np.float32)
m2 = np.random.normal(size = [size,size]).astype(np.float32)

ctx = cl.create_some_context(interactive=True)
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

a = pycl_array.to_device(queue, m1)
b = pycl_array.to_device(queue, m2)
res = pycl_array.empty_like(a)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void multiplymatrices(const unsigned int size, __global const float * a, 
    __global const float * b, __global float * res) {

    int i = get_global_id(0); 
    int j = get_global_id(1);

    res[size * i + j] = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        res[size * i + j] += a[k + size * j] * b[i + size * k];
    }

    }
    """).build()

t = time.time()
task = prg.multiplymatrices(queue, m1.shape, None, np.int32(size), a.data, b.data, res.data)

task.wait()
tot_time = time.time()-t
print("gflops", 2*size**3/(tot_time*1000**3))
```

Comment: In doing further experimentation, I am getting speedups of about 10x as expected with a simple sum of two vectors, I think it simply depends on the efficiency of the code.

Comment: Use registers for temp accumulators. Dont use global memory unless it is necessary.

Comment: By-the-book matrix multiplication unfortunately exhibits memory access patterns which aren't ideal for GPUs. As @huseyintugrulbuyukisik has pointed out, don't accumulate the result directly in `res[size * i + j]` but a local variable which you write out to your result matrix only once. Second, the access patterns produced by `a[k + size * j]` and `b[i + size * k]` lookups are difficult for the GPU to batch across work items, so you are almost certainly causing more memory reads than strictly necessary.

Comment: A lot has been written about implementing matrix multiplication in OpenCL efficiently - e.g. copying matrix blocks to local memory before performing that part of the multiplication. I suspect you'll be able to find some code that runs vastly more efficiently with a bit of a web search.

Comment: 1st, like said, don't accumulate in global mem. 2nd, if you want memory access pattern to be efficient, you need to transpose one of the matrices. Very good read on the subject is here: https://cnugteren.github.io/tutorial/pages/page1.html

Comment: Thanks for all the input everyone, will report back with some modified code and results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion to use a local register to accumulate the results, I modified my code as follows, getting about 90 gflops at about 360 GB/s of memory bandwidth (which is the maximum bandwidth my GPU is capable of). Improving the gflops would require a more sophisticated matrix multiplication algorithm which reuses the same data stored in cache multiple times, but is outside the scope of this question.

```
__kernel void multiplymatrices(const unsigned int size, __global const float * a, 
__global const float * b, __global float * res) {

int i = get_global_id(0); 
int j = get_global_id(1);
float temp = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
{
    temp += a[k + size * j] * b[i + size * k];
}
res[size * i + j] = temp;
}
```

EDIT: For those looking for an example of fast matrix multiplication, which showcases using local memory with workgroups as well as 2D register tiling, I have created the below based on the tutorial [here](https://cnugteren.github.io/tutorial/pages/page2.html). It gets 1.4 TFLOPs on my GPU.

```
prg4 = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void multiplymatrices(const unsigned int size, __global const float * A, 
__global const float * B, __global float * res) {

int ig = get_group_id(0);
int jg = get_group_id(1);
int il = get_local_id(0);
int jl = get_local_id(1);

const int memtile = 64;
const int regtile = 4;
volatile int il2;
volatile int jl2;
int iglob = memtile*ig + regtile*il;
int jglob = memtile*jg + regtile*jl;

__local float Asub[64][64];
__local float Bsub[64][64];
float acc[4][4];
float Areg;
float Breg[4];

for (int k = 0; k < regtile; k++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < regtile; m++) {
        acc[k][m] = 0;
    }
}

for (int l = 0; l < size/memtile; l++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < regtile; k++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < regtile; m++) {
            il2 = il*regtile + k;
            jl2 = jl*regtile + m;
            Asub[il2][jl2] = A[size*(iglob + k) + memtile*l + jl2];
            Bsub[il2][jl2] = B[size*(memtile*l + il2) + jglob + m];
        }
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for (int k = 0; k < regtile; k++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < regtile; r++) {
            Breg[r] = Bsub[il*regtile+k][jl*regtile+r];
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < regtile; m++) {
            Areg = Asub[il*regtile+m][jl*regtile+k];
            for (int r = 0; r < regtile; r++) {
                acc[k][m] += Areg*Breg[r];
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < regtile; k++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < regtile; m++) {
        res[size*(iglob+k)+jglob+m] = acc[k][m];
    }
}
}
""").build()

t = time.time()
memtile = 64
regtile = 4
wgsize = int(memtile/regtile)
global_size = int(size/regtile)
task = prg4.multiplymatrices(queue, (global_size,global_size), (wgsize,wgsize), np.int32(size), a.data, b.data, res.data)

queue.finish()
tot_time = time.time()-t
print("gflops", 2*size**3/(tot_time*1000**3))
print("GB/s total", 2*4*size**3/(tot_time*1000**3))
print("GB/s global", 2*4*size**3/(memtile*tot_time*1000**3))
```

Comment: I want to comment that there is a good chance that the matrix multiplication code is somehow wrong, but I hope that it will serve as a nice example of a few techniques.